# Different HTML codes depending on table data is fetched from

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a PHP code that looks like this:

```
<?php
  if($_GET['mode'] == ""){ 
   $get_indhold = mysql_query("
 (SELECT * FROM Pictures
   ORDER BY Dato DESC LIMIT 1) 
 union all (SELECT * FROM Videos 
   ORDER BY Dato DESC LIMIT 1)
 order by Dato DESC LIMIT 1");
  $indhold = mysql_fetch_array($get_indhold);
?>
```

As you can see, it fetches data from two different tables, showing only the latest content sorted by date.
It Works.
What I want to do now, is to show a different HTML code depending on which table it is currently fetching data from. I have tried some if/elseif statements, but nothing seems to Work. 
The reason I want to do it, is because there are different embed codes for Pictures and video. If I just insert both codes into my document, I end up with an empty video player when the code fetches a Picture from my database.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please provide some of those codes that did not work

Comment: `<?php
    if $table(Pictures=ACTIVE) {
    echo "*HTML CODE*";
    } elseif {
    echo "*HTML CODE 2";
    }
    ?>`

I have just tried writing "ACTIVE" but I really have no clue what to do. I have tried the PHP manual but I did not find anything.

Comment: print out an example of a row from what your query returns and add this to your question. -1 until then. you can't be helped if you don't provide stuff to go on

Comment: I'm not really sure you understand my question then. This has nothing to do with my Query, I just need a php tag or whatever to check if it is the "Pictures" or "Videos" table the latest content is being fetched from. I have heard you can use a tag like "UNION" to find out but I still dont have a clue which one will do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with this (but if you already happen to have a value thats unique for either pictures or videos, you **should** use that as the identifier).

```
$query="SELECT *, 1 AS is_picture FROM Pictures 
            UNION ALL
        SELECT *, 0 AS is_picture FROM Videos
            ORDER BY Dato DESC LIMIT 1";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if($row["is_picture"]){
        //do picture stuff
    }else{
        //do video stuff
    }
}
```